# Php's echo does not close properly

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Hello I have this src path in codeigniter

```
src="<?php echo base_url();?>photos/<?php echo $data1; echo '"/>';?>
```

The problem is that when i'm going to continue my code it seems that all the below code is inside an `echo "";` it looks like the echo is still open.. For example i want to continue my code with a `html` div`and the`div` is still on an echo area.. Thanks

Comment: Show more code ...... below the last echo.

Comment: there is nothing more, below that code i just open a div, and it looks like the previous echo is not finnished..

Comment: right remove the last echo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are inside of quotes of src-property.

```
src="<?php echo base_url();?>photos/<?php echo $data1;?>" />
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
src="<?php echo base_url();?>photos/<?php echo $data1;?>" />
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<?php echo 'src="'.base_url().'photos/'.$data.'" />'; ?>
```

or

```
 <?php echo '<img src="'.base_url().'photos/'.$data.'" />'; ?>
```

Comment: This is a better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you haven't closed the last echo . tyr this

```
src="<?php echo base_url();?>photos/<?php echo $data1;?>" />
```

there is more better way of doing this in codeigniter. pass the url as the arguement to the base_url function

```
src="<?php echo base_url('photos/'.$data1);?>" />
```

try it. for more details: [click](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)